# Why can't I set up alias for shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, alias

I have edited my .bash_aliases to contain the following line

```
alias shutdown='sudo shutdown -h now'
```

but when I try to run the alias it gives this error message

```
shutdown: illegal time value
Try `shutdown --help' for more information.
```

It seems like all my aliases containing the shutdown-command is giving this error message.

Any ideas?

Comment: Strange, it works for me

Comment: Maybe you just need to logout and back on to reload your profile changes?

Comment: i agree with Bruno Pereira and look here: http://www.howtogeek.com/73768/how-to-use-aliases-to-customize-ubuntu-commands/

Answer (score 0):

It works with previous versions. (I can clearly remember I have done this before)
However, in newer versions of Ubuntu (say 13.10), "now" is no longer a legal value. We should use "0" instead. So now your alias becomes:

```
alias shutdown='sudo shutdown -h 0'
```